# SQLException with SQL state '42601', error code '-104', DRIVER=3.59.81

Tags: mysql, xml, jakarta-ee, db2

I'm having this Error which i couldn't trace, any suggestion, where should i look please?

```
Translating SQLException with SQL state '42601', error code '-104', message [DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=);D ID_XXX IN
             (;<value_expr_body>, DRIVER=3.59.81];
### Error querying database.  Cause: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=);D ID_XXX IN
             (;<value_expr_body>, DRIVER=3.59.81
```

The problem is the "SQLERRMC" shows nothing !

Comment: MySQL and db2 - do you really mean both? could you add the actual SQL query.

Comment: ... `AND ID_XXX IN
    <foreach collection="xxxx" item="idXX" open="(" separator="," close=")">` ... The issue source

Comment: That doesn't look like valid `DB2` syntax to me.

Comment: Not real sure what you are trying to accomplish. Please edit your question, and add what you are trying to do, and the SQL you are using to do it. Please give us the whole statement so that we have the appropriate context. Then we will be better able to help you.

Comment: SQLERRMC does not show nothing, the error message shows SQLERRMC=`);D ID_XXX IN
             (;<value_expr_body>`

Answer (score 0):

**Error -104**
is Caused by Some **ILLEGAL TOKEN**,
Your SQL query have some error in **Syntax**.

Check Your Query

Comment: That's not the problem, the SQL query have no syntax error :/, i know that -104 code is for ILLEGAL TOKENS, but it is not the case !

Comment: Can you just add the SQL query

Comment: even I am facing same issue, have you got some solution